# Nhibernate eager fetch childeren of childeren with parents

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

We want to get all childeren of childeren eagerly fetched from nhibernate.
The problem we have is that we have multi leves of stuff.
I will try to explain.

[image]

That is a small version of the ERD.

How this looks for us is as followed

[image]

I hope  this will explain the situation.

What we want now is we have the last Object Id. 
We want all childeren and all nextversions of those childeren and the group and Area.
Also we want if there are more (next) groups in the area of the object we have we want all those objects as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by making a list of AreaIDs and eagerly fetch all groups with all actions with all previous versions of the area's I needed by looking up from the objects i got till i have the Area and fetching it when it was not in the list (and then add the Id to the list)